# Find the position of a specific number that appear first in the list [python]

Tags: python, list, position, duplicates

So I want to find a number that appears more than once in the list. I want the position of the first one.

Example: Say I want 3

```
     s = [1,2,3,4,5,3,9,8]  => s[2] appears first
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def first_dup( seq ):
    # keep track of the positions
    seen = {}
    for pos,item in enumerate(seq):
        if item in seen:
            # saw it before, so its a duplicate
            return seen[item]
        else:
            # first time we see it, store the pos
            seen[item] = pos
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit ambiguous question.

If you just want to find index of first occurrence of specific element, you should use [list.index()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
index = s.index(3)
```

But if you

> want to find a number that appears
>   more than once in the list

in general (without element value given), seems you can

- either do simple O(N^2) search in array (check all elements of the list for each element, till duplication is found)
- or do sort, find duplicated element in sorted list and then find index of duplicated element in the original array with list.index() method - this will take O(N*log(N)) because of sort.

Comment: Counting is O(N) time + O(N) space, and finding the index is O(N) too. Sorting is O(N log N).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this should do the trick:

```
s = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.count(s[i]) > 1:
        return i
```

This should give you the index of the first occurrence of the first element that appears multiple times in the list

If this is not what you're after, please leave a comment and I'll edit the code.

Comment: Upvoted because of the simplicity, but it has O(N^2) running time which makes it impractical for large lists. Also, it would be better to use enumerate(s) to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

The function below returns the index of the first appearance of a duplicate

```
def find_first_duplicate(num_list):
        track_list =[]
        index = 0
        for e in num_list:
            if(e not in track_list):
                track_list += [e]
            else: ## found!
                return index
            index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it..

If present, it will return the first index..
If there are no duplicates available, it will raise IndexError.

```
[s.index(_) for _ in s if s.count(_) > 1][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing it:

```
from operator import countOf

def multindex(seq):
    """ find index of first value occurring more than once
        in a sequence, else raise ValueError if there aren't any
    """
    for i,v in enumerate(seq):
        if countOf(seq, v) > 1:
            return i
    else:
        raise ValueError

print 's[{}] is first value in the list occurring more than once'.format(multindex(s))
# s[2] is first value in the list occurring more than once
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s.index(3)
```

will return `2`, as you desire.

`index` will raise `ValueError` if the specified item is not in the list.

Comment: You could just have written `2`, it would be as useful. The problem is how to find out which item is a duplicate.

Comment: It's obviously not as simple as that or I wouldn't have received three upvotes or interpreted it the way I did. Read the title of the question. It's entirely possible I mis-read the asker's intention, but for someone completely new to Python this is an entirely "useful" answer.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is:  "Given a list, what is the index of the first duplicated item?"